# android inheritance activity(Base - Main activity)

Tags: android

I am having a problem about implemeting android apps. 
I made baseActivity which is that base of other applications and other applications.

These are my code.

First, BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,int layoutId) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layoutId);

        Button menuBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuBtn);
        menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("bss","menu");
            }   
        }); 
    }
}
```

And the other one is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState,R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Now I have a question! When I was click the menu button, click listener did not act. It did not print log message and any action. So, I have a problem to make my application. Is it related with life-cycle or How can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is setting the Content View twice. Following is the sequence of your code.

1. `setContentView()`
2. `Add button listener`
3. `setContentView()`

Statement # 2, adds the button listener and it is all good till now. But as soon as you reset the content view on statement # 3, the previous settings get void. And the button gets reinitialized and the onClickListener is no more attached to the button.

Answer (score 3):

I do not like the way you are forcing thing, still if you want to make it works this way you have remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` from `MainActivity`, that's because one you call again  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in the sublcass, the view hierarchy for that `Activity` will be recreated invalidating what you have done in the super class

Comment: cool. Could you bother yourself explaining the reason of the downvote?

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem! Cool! However, why do not like this way?

Comment: because you are changing the onCreate's callback in you `BaseActivity`

Comment: But I think it is essential. This is because if I directly set a one layout, then it is not good at using other activities that is inherited from baseActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the contentview from BaseActivity and put

```
  Button menuBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuBtn);
        menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("bss","menu");
            }   
        });
```

into MainActivity. The Base activity should be SuperClass and MainActivity subclass all the actions for view shold be initialize into the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,int layoutId) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            }

         public int getLayoutXML() {
            return -1;
        }

        public abstract int getMenuId();
        }
```

After this use this BaseActivity class like this :

```
public class service_detail extends BaseActivity {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           //  Use button like this:
Button menuBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuBtn);
        menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("bss","menu");
            }   
        }); 

}

    @Override
        public int getMenuId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getLayoutXML() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return R.layout.service_detail;
        }

}
```